# Min width not working and max-width acting for empty div

Tags: html, css

**min-width property is not working forp tag.**

[image: What i got]

**This is my expected behaviour**

[image: I need like this]

My code:

```css
p {
  max-width: calc(100% - 500px);
  min-width: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae accusantium fuga odio enim, quaerat assumenda in dolorum consequuntur est perspiciatis consectetur temporibus, nulla voluptas ducimus, neque dolorem cum quod autem.</p>
<p>a</p>
```

Comment: what is your question? what behavior do you expect?

Comment: Try setting `display: inline-block`

Comment: The reason why it is only displaying as max width is because `p` by default is display block so the natural width is 100%. Change it to `display: inline-block` and it will behave correctly. If you want each p to take up a line like block element then go with the fit-content answer

Comment: What does the WhatsApp screenshot have to do with this question? If it's not related, please consider removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container for the `<p>` tags

```css
.my-class {
  max-width: calc(100% - 500px);
  min-width: 10px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.my-class p {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='my-class'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae accusantium fuga odio enim, quaerat assumenda in dolorum consequuntur est perspiciatis consectetur temporibus, nulla voluptas ducimus, neque dolorem cum quod autem.</p>
</div>

<div class='my-class'>
  <p>a</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need a container?

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing what you really asked, but here's my answer. I would added
`width: fit-content` to make div automatically size to content width.

```css
p {
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px); /* 500px changed to 100px only to make it fit better in this example snippet */
    min-width: 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae accusantium fuga odio enim, quaerat assumenda in dolorum consequuntur est perspiciatis consectetur temporibus, nulla voluptas ducimus, neque dolorem cum quod autem.</p>
<p>a</p>
```

Comment: this beats out making the `p` inline-block because this will keep the block free of other messages that are short